# ASP.NET/HTML - How would I update an SQLDataSource with a <select><option>?

Tags: html, sql, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET HTML website in which I want to update my SQLDataSource SELECT command using a drop-down menu. The user can select to sort by Date, Duration or Player, and the GridView will update showing the new, sorted results from my mdf database. I'm really not sure at all how to approach this as I am fairly new to ASP.NET. I could just do with some pointers on how to go about it, and what method to use. I can google tutorials, the problem is knowing what to google. Any advice greatly appreciated :)
My code:

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="RunsData">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PlayerId" HeaderText="PlayerId" SortExpression="PlayerId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Duration" HeaderText="Duration" SortExpression="Duration" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="VersionId" HeaderText="VersionId" SortExpression="VersionId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DateUploaded" HeaderText="DateUploaded" SortExpression="DateUploaded" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="RunsData" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [PlayerId], [Duration], [VersionId], [DateUploaded] FROM [Run] ORDER BY [Duration]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </form>
    <div>
        <label class="label" for="version">Version: </label>
        <select name="version" id="version">
            <option value="lev1">Level 1</option>
            <option value="lev1to3">Level 1-3</option>
            <option value="lev8">Level 8</option>
            <option value="lev17">Level 17</option>
        </select>
        <label class="label" for="sortby">Sort By: </label>
        <select name="sortby" id="sortby">
            <option value="duration">Duration</option>
            <option value="date">Date</option>
            <option value="player">Player</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Replace select lists with asp:DropDownList and then you can create a method on server that fires on index change to update/modify select command in RunsData that's used to fill GridView1

Comment: You can do this with server controls. **BUT** if you do it that way then the page will need to reload from scratch and you will need to re-run the query every time the user changes the sort order. Instead, I'd look to do this via javascript. It will help your web server scale better and make the page more responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first up, I would think it is better to have the filters at the top (above) the grid, and not below? (just a idea).

and in fact, even better idea would be to drop in the two combo boxes RIGHT into the grid heading - even better!!!

but, lets take this one step at a time.

First up, I recommend we dump (remove) the data source in the web page. The can be handy, wizards generate them - thank you much - all good. However, EVEN when I often use a wizard to create the GV, I THEN blow out the data source, and use code. And when is a GOOD idea to use code to fill the GV?

Why of course when you want to filter it!!!

So, lets do this:

Delete/remove the Sqldata source - we not going to use it.

Remove this from GV -  DataSourceID="RunsData"

Also, you clear used the wizards to create and setup that GV, but then now use select html? Why not use DropDown lists? The wizards not only can build them for you (like the GV, they also have a rich .net event model. And you can shove, drive the dropdown list just like the GV (they are data source friendly).

So, we going to assume this markup now:

```
    <div style="float:left">
    <label class="label" for="version">Version: </label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="cboVersion" runat="server" Width="150px">
            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">Level 1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1-3">Level  1-3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="8">Level 8</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="17">Level 17</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>

    <div style="float:left;padding-left:25px">

        <label class="label" for="sortby">Sort By:</label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="cboSortBy" runat="server" Width="150px">
            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="duration">Duration</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="DateUploaded">Date</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Player</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;height:10px"></div>  <%-- Start new line for grid --%>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="RunsData">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PlayerId"     HeaderText="PlayerId"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Duration"     HeaderText="Duration"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="VersionId"    HeaderText="VersionId"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateUploaded" HeaderText="DateUploaded" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</form>
```

So, note that just like GV the dropdown list as a edit items option, like this:

[image]

And then you get this:

[image]

Also, when you want level say 1-3 is that column a number type?

And as noted, I put the filters tat the top of the grid. Since your placing the filers below the grid? You have to explain that goal - not seen filters on the bottom of a grid in about 20 years now - maybe some desktop apps? But SUPER rare. Since that choice is SUPER RARE? Then you may well have a good reason, but I placed the filter at the top. In fact, we would/could consider placing the dropdowns in the header of the GV (and that is allowed!!!). But, hey, one step at a time.

I also don't grasp, see the need for two forms on the page? (again, might be a reason, but you better have one heck of a good and great reason for that choice).

So, we now have this:

```
    <div style="float:left">
    <label class="label" for="version">Version: </label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="cboVersion" runat="server" Width="150px" AutoPostBack="true"> 
            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">Level 1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1,3">Level  1-3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="8">Level 8</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="17">Level 17</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>

    <div style="float:left;padding-left:25px">

        <label class="label" for="sortby">Sort By:</label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="cboSortBy" runat="server" Width="150px" AutoPostBack="true" >
            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="duration">Duration</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="DateUploaded">Date</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Player</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;height:10px"></div>  <%-- Start new line for grid --%>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        Width="30%" CssClass="table">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PlayerId"     HeaderText="PlayerId"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Duration"     HeaderText="Duration"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="VersionId"    HeaderText="VersionId"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateUploaded" HeaderText="DateUploaded" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Note careful we added/allow/have a BLANK choice for the two combo boxes.

Ok, so now our code to load up the grid like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        loadgrid()
    End If

End Sub
Sub loadgrid()

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT PlayerId, Duration, VersionId, DateUploaded FROM [Run]", conn)

            ' add filter
            Dim strWhere As String = ""
            If cboVersion.Text <> "" Then

                If InStr(cboVersion.SelectedItem.Value, "-") = 0 Then
                    ' one value
                    cmdSQL.CommandText &= " WHERE VersionID = @id"
                    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cboVersion.SelectedItem.Value
                Else
                    ' we have  range
                    Dim MyRnage() As String = Split(cboVersion.SelectedItem.Value, "-")
                    cmdSQL.CommandText &= " WHERE VersionID is between @lower and @upper"
                    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@lower", SqlDbType.Int).Value = MyRnage(0)
                    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@upper", SqlDbType.Int).Value = MyRnage(1)
                End If

            End If


            ' add order by
            If cboSortBy.Text = "" Then
                cmdSQL.CommandText &= " ORDER BY Duration"
            Else
                cmdSQL.CommandText &= " ORDER BY " & cboSortBy.SelectedItem.Value
            End If

            Dim rstData As New DataTable
            conn.Open
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            GridView1.DataSource = rstData
            GridView1.DataBind()

        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Since we have auto post-back, then for both the sort by combo, filter by, then we have two event stubs here.

```
Protected Sub cboVersion_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboVersion.SelectedIndexChanged
    loadgrid()
End Sub

Protected Sub cboSortBy_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboSortBy.SelectedIndexChanged
    loadgrid()
End Sub
```

## Edit:

The follow up question was where did TEST4 come from? Why of course it is my  own setting.

From VS menu, project->"my project"->settings.

There we go to settings, and then do this:

[image]

So then in above hit the [...] and you get the connection string builder.

I mean, you can manually edit web config, but that's kind of human torture, and using the above settings is oh so much easy. So for application settings, you can use the above to create settings for your application. Say company name, or connection strings, or whatever. Those settings are placed in web.config for you. So, you not limited to just connection strings, but all kinds of constants settings such as company name, maybe company address etc.

Comment: This is great, many thanks. I have 1 error which is the `Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)` line, is the TEST4 meant to be replaced by something maybe? the error is `TEST4 Is not a Member of 'MySettings'`

Comment: Well, it is assumed you created and used application setting before? See my edit - yes, I created a connection string called TEST4. I would assume a MUCH better name you would choose then that - see my edit in above. Using application settings goes back a VERY long time - assumed to be a basic skill of using Visual Studio. But, see my new edit at the end of the above post - I show how and where I created that setting. So not a lot different then you choosing a name for a variable, it your choice as to what name you give near everything in code

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I am fairly new to ASP as you can likely tell. After some debugging, the code seems to work when initially started. It calls the first `loadgrid()` and successfully sorts the gridview to whatever SQL command I use, however nothing i select afterwards in the menus seems to call `loadgrid` again. Here is my code as it is highly likely I've put something in the wrong place https://pastebin.com/HvVkGAXJ and here is my debug output https://pastebin.com/iNdz8BJW

Comment: You could have pasted the code here - easer for many readers to see a issue. Remember, I don't have your data - so that code is "off the top" or so called "air code". I did notice that I used a 1,3 for the value, but I check/test for  a "-" and split base on a "-". So that 1,3 value in the dropdown needs to be a 1-3 for that selection to work. Most of the code you have looks good - and good for shoving in some debug writelines - good for you!!! I would double check the field names I used for sort - they might be typed in wrong. So, that code looks quite good. Check the column names in dropdown